# Massive performance downgrade in Spring Batch application after update the Spring Boot Dependencies version from 2.4.2 to 2.7.6

Tags: spring-boot, performance, spring-batch, spring-kafka

We have upgraded a Spring Batch application in which the Spring Boot Dependencies is upgrade from version 2.4.2 to 2.7.6. Unfortunately we noticed a performance downgrade in processing the same file and eventually sending to Kafka using `KafkaItemWriter`.

We tried to do a few baby steps from version 2.4.2 to 2.4.4 and found that the version 2.4.2 uses the Spring Batch version 4.3.1 while the version 2.4.4 uses the Spring Batch version 4.3.2. To my point of view, it seems sending the data to Kafka asynchronously in the Spring Batch version 4.3.1 and sending the data to Kafka synchronously from the Spring Batch version 2.4.4 according to this [release note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/releases/tag/4.3.2) where a change is made to wait for the result from `KafkaItemWriter`.

We tried to wrote our own implementation of `KafkaItemWriter` which reverted the changed made in the PR of the new version (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/3827/commits/3acbaaa73dbaed3ea5e5e92c53b75780c50c86b6) and it could give us the good result but not sure if it is required to do a flush explicitly which could cause us any issues of losing data to Kafka broker down the line.

```java
public class NoWaitKafkaItemWriter<K, T> extends KafkaItemWriter<K, T> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(NoWaitKafkaItemWriter.class);

    @Override
    protected void writeKeyValue(K key, T value) {
        LOGGER.info("About to write key {} value {}", key, value);

        if (this.delete) {
            this.kafkaTemplate.sendDefault(key, null);
        } else {
            this.kafkaTemplate.sendDefault(key, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void flush() {
        // do nothing
        LOGGER.info("Do nothing in flush");
    }
}
```

```java
@Bean
public KafkaItemWriter<String, MyKafkaObject> getKafkaItemWriter(
            KafkaTemplate<String, MyKafkaObject> kafkaProducerTemplate) {

    LOGGER.info("Creating KafkaItemWriter that doesn't wait");

    KafkaItemWriter writer = new NoWaitKafkaItemWriter();
    writer.setKafkaTemplate(kafkaProducerTemplate);
    writer.setItemKeyMapper(this.kafkaItemKeyMapper);

    return writer;
}
```

We also tried with the timeout in 0 millisecond but it wouldn't help much since it is still waiting for the flush completion.

```java
@Bean
public KafkaItemWriter<String, MyKafkaObject> getKafkaItemWriter(
        KafkaTemplate<String, MyKafkaObject> kafkaProducerTemplate) {

    LOGGER.info("Creating KafkaItemWriter");

    return new KafkaItemWriterBuilder<String, MyKafkaObject>()
            .kafkaTemplate(kafkaProducerTemplate)
            .itemKeyMapper(this.kafkaItemKeyMapper)
            .timeout(0)
            .build();
}
```

We are wondering if there is any options that we could make the application running asynchronously as it was before that change?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the fact that it is now slow more of a symptom of your architecture/job setup as it is for the writer? Maybe your chunk sizes are too large? There might be a lot of latency on your network for connecting/sending to kafka?

Comment: I am not quite sure what your first question is. Could you explain a bit more please? The chunk size is only 5 for testing and we have been testing in different machines so I don't think there is any latency involved.

Comment: latency as in the connection to kafka. Sending to kafka should be pretty fast and I doubt that waiting for the result will have a massive impact. Hence the suggestion that the fact that it now is slow is more of a symptom in your setup/architecture then an issue with the writer.